# Javascript only runs alert

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to piece together a basic page using PHP & JS to take me to a google map related to a search box. However the JS script will only run with an alert, no other function type will run: 
The address bar just changes to "Domainx.com/?searchButton="

The code for the button is:

```
                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg" name="searchButton" onclick="searchFunction()">Search </button>
```

and directly under it (within the body) is have my script:

```
<script>
function searchFunction() {
alert("pressed");
}

</script>
```

When i change the alert to anything else i.e.  window.location.href = "http://www.google.com"

it simple stays on the page and only the address bar changes.

Comment: you probably want to use `window.open("http://www.google.com/search?q=the_meaning_of_life")`

Comment: ok now that works, Thanks.
but how do i load a new page instead of opening a new window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably wanted to use `window.open("http://www.google.com/search?q=the_meaning_of_life");`

If you wanted to use reload onclick, the following should work:

`<input type="button" value="Reload Page" onClick="window.location.reload()">`

There is an example of how to dow it here - http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/page/reload.html

Comment: No problem, rememer MDN has a good source of javascript stuff you can look at too :)